@Html.ListBoxFor setting the initial selected item
I have a web page which has a listbox which is correctly populated as below
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Item, ViewBag.Ingreds as SelectList,                                   
new { @id = "item", @size = 5 })

This is correctly populated with the contents of the ViewBag but what I cannot figure is how to have a particular line in the listbox selected on page load. The text value to be selected should match the value held in @ingred.Item which is populated here.
testbox.Models.IngredModelAdmin ingred in ViewBag.Ingred

Can anyone show me how to select the correct line in the listbox matching the value in @ingred.Item please.
Thanks in advance

Per my understanding, mvc render the content in the server side, so that we  shall have 2 options for us to set the default selected Item, one is like what this answer do, set the selected option when new item options. Another option is writing js to change the option after the html content already rendered in the browser, write js to operate the  based on the Ingred value. If you wanna a sample, then you might share more code snippet.

Thanks, that link you supplied looks like the answer to me

I'm glad to get your confirmation : )
